# EditText receiving key events when inputType is text despite the Dialog.OnKeyListener consuming all the events

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a `Dialog` with a `Dialog.OnKeyListener` that intercepts some keys.

For testing purposes, my `onKey` method is always returning `true` which means that my `Dialog.OnKeyListener` is consuming all the key events.

I have a `EditText` in my `Dialog` and I have found that if I set as the `inputType` other type than `text` (`number` for example), the `EditText` doesn't receive any key event and behaves like it's non editable (as expected because my `Dialog.OnKeyListener` is consuming all the events), but if I set the `inputType` as `inputType="text"`, the `EditText` receives all the key events (it's editable).

For my example I have a `Dialog` with an `OnKeyListener` consuming all the events and two `EditText`s, one with `inputType="text"` receiving key events and other with `inputType="number"` not receiving any event.

**dialog_test.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="10dp">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pass1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="inputType text (receives key events)"
        android:inputType="text"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pass2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="inputType number (doesn't receive key events)"
        android:inputType="number"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**TestDialog.java**

```
public class TestDialog extends Dialog {
    public TestDialog(final Context context) {
        super(context);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_test);
        this.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        this.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(final DialogInterface arg0, final int keyCode,
                                 final KeyEvent event) {
                // This listener is consuming all the events
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Why does the `EditText` receives key events when `inputType` is `text` despite the `Dialog.OnKeyListener` consuming all the events?

**Edit:** I`m using Google Keyboard on Android 5.1.1 testing on a BQ Aquaris M5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because software keyboards don't send key events.  They send edit commands via the InputConnection.  If you want to intercept those, you need to subclass EditText and override the InputConnection sent to the keyboard in onCreateInputConnection.

Or if you just want to see what's coming from the keyboard, use a TextWatcher.

Comment: Then, why I can't type anything on the `EditText` when `inputType="number"`?

Comment: Maybe your keyboard decided to send key events for the numeric keyboard?  Soft keyboards are allowed to send key events, its just not normal.  Of course every keyboard does things differently, and there's at least a half dozen major keyboards out there, and dozens of minor.  I have no idea which one you're using.  But most of the majors use commitText almost exclusively, although some will use completionText which is a way of sending text that isn't fully there until completed (this is what is happening when you see underlined text while typing).  That also won't appear as keystrokes.

Comment: I have edited my answer to point out that I'm using Google Keyboard on Android 5.1.1. I will study how soft keyboards work and I will try to intercept key events and compare the results with the TextWatchers as you propose. Anyway this is not limiting my development, it's just a strange (unexpected) behaviour that I found and I wanted to know what lied behind it. Thanks a lot for your answer!